# Why does the POST request not contain request data (Restangular)

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, restangular

I am trying to do a POST request on the routes /api/questionnaires and /api/assessors. When i inspect the POST request it contains no data. But when i check the variables 'newQuestionnaire' and 'assessor' in the js console they are defined.

```
$scope.save = function() {
    var questionnaires = Restangular.all('questionnaires');
    var newQuestionnaire = {questionnaire: {id:$scope.selectedTemplate.id}};
    questionnaires.post(newQuestionnaire).then(function(result){
        if($scope.newAssessment.participants) {
            for(var i = 0; i< $scope.newAssessment.participants.length; i++) {
                         $scope.createAssessor($scope.newAssessment.participants[i], result.questionnaire.id);
            }
        }
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
$scope.createAssessor = function(email, questionnaire_id) {
    var assessor = new models.Assessor(email, questionnaire_id);
    Restangular.all('assessors').post(assessor);
}
```

Comment: I was stupid, didn't see the requestinterceptor had commented lines